# Can't Install Nessus in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: xubuntu, nessus

I tried with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install nessus
```

But It shows:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package nessus is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
openvas-client:i386 openvas-client

E: Package 'nessus' has no installation candidate
```

What to do now?

Comment: This looks like it is more specific, and @jamess answer is precise with regard to a nessus solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are no native Nessus packages for 14.04 LTS. See [Here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/trusty/+source/nessus-core). This is because starting with Nessus 3, Tenable switched to a proprietary license.

Instead, Ubuntu provides [OpenVAS](http://www.openvas.org/), a fork of the GPL Nessus 2.2 codebase.

You can install the client and server for OpenVAS with apt:

```
sudo apt-get install openvas-client openvas-server openvas-plugins-base openvas-plugins-dfsg
```

If you strongly prefer Nessus, the current versions are available under a proprietary license from [Tenable](http://www.tenable.com/)