# How do I install nessus on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, nessus

I have tried installing using the other guides, but they either recommend using apt-get (I tried, that doesn't work at all, it can not locate the packages) or using the regular download and just installing it that way. I have tried using the official download, but although the installation using qapt completes successfully, I am unable to launch it or anything else. Basically I want a guide on how to install it, that includes what repos to add, what to install, and how to configure it. Please help me with this, someone recently broke into a couple computers on my home network and I need to find the fix ASAP before they do a (literal) drive by attack again.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Download Nessus from [here](http://www.tenable.com/products/nessus/select-your-operating-system). Choose the Ubuntu packages (or the Debian ones)
2. Open a Terminal and go to the download directory (`cd`)
3. Run `sudo dpkg -i Nessus*.deb`. Enter root password.
4. Start it `sudo /etc/init.d/nessusd start`
5. Open a browser and go to `https://localhost:8834/`

See more on [Samiux's Blog](http://samiux.blogspot.ro/2013/05/howto-nessus-on-ubuntu-desktop-1204-lts.html). Check also: [Can't Install Nessus in Ubuntu 14.04 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/472599/cant-install-nessus-in-ubuntu-14-04-lts)